# RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity. Intent getting Extras

Tags: android, android-intent, nullpointerexception, bundle, runtimeexception

I really don't know what's wrong:
I've made function, that moves user to AddNewQuestionClass

```
//function is in Activity Class
public void wroc(String sciezka){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, AddNewQuestion.class);
    intent.putExtra("sciezka1", sciezka);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

I'm also sending "sciezka" variable. Now, I'm getting this variable in AddNewQuesionClass:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    sciezka_do_pliku_z_obrazem = bundle.getString("sciezka1");
    Uri myUri = Uri.parse(sciezka_do_pliku_z_obrazem);
    try {

        Bitmap jakisobraz = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), myUri);
        obrazekdoedycji.setImageBitmap(jakisobraz);
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("EO", " " + e);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, something don't works:

```
12-10 20:21:12.213: E/AndroidRuntime(9173): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-10 20:21:12.213: E/AndroidRuntime(9173): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {app.piotrek.learning/app.piotrek.learning.AddNewQuestion}: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-10 20:21:12.213: E/AndroidRuntime(9173):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2701)
12-10 20:21:12.213: E/AndroidRuntime(9173):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2729)
12-10 20:21:12.213: E/AndroidRuntime(9173):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2215)
12-10 20:21:12.213: E/AndroidRuntime(9173):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:142)
12-10 20:21:12.213: E/AndroidRuntime(9173):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1208)
12-10 20:21:12.213: E/AndroidRuntime(9173):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-10 20:21:12.213: E/AndroidRuntime(9173):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-10 20:21:12.213: E/AndroidRuntime(9173):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4931)
12-10 20:21:12.213: E/AndroidRuntime(9173):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-10 20:21:12.213: E/AndroidRuntime(9173):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-10 20:21:12.213: E/AndroidRuntime(9173):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
12-10 20:21:12.213: E/AndroidRuntime(9173):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:558)
12-10 20:21:12.213: E/AndroidRuntime(9173):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-10 20:21:12.213: E/AndroidRuntime(9173): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-10 20:21:12.213: E/AndroidRuntime(9173):     at app.piotrek.learning.AddNewQuestion.onResume(AddNewQuestion.java:185)
12-10 20:21:12.213: E/AndroidRuntime(9173):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1184)
12-10 20:21:12.213: E/AndroidRuntime(9173):     at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:5082)
12-10 20:21:12.213: E/AndroidRuntime(9173):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2691)
12-10 20:21:12.213: E/AndroidRuntime(9173):     ... 12 more
```

This is #185 line (there is an error):

```
 sciezka_do_pliku_z_obrazem = bundle.getString("sciezka1");
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Try grabbing it from the extras, not the bundle.

Comment: If you haven't solved this yet, can you print out the value before butting it into the intent extras and after retrieving from the bundle, so we can confirm that what's going in isn't null and what's coming out is?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
getIntent().getStringExtra("sciezka1");
```

rather than bundle...
I  hope it will solve ur problem

Comment: the same error :/ When I put this into try/catch, in logs I have this: 12-11 21:01:04.670: E/EO(19298):  java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: /storage/sdcard0/AAProgramDoNauki/uuu.png

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your variable **sciezka** is null, so later in `onResume()` when `bundle.getString('sciezka')` the value of **sciezka** is empty thus throwing a null pointer exception.

Make sure **sciezka** is not empty, you can do a `Log.i` after

`intent.putExtra("sciezka1", sciezka);` to dump variable **sciezka** to confirm this.

Comment: sciezka certainly isn't null :/

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the bundle you are trying to call method `getString()` on is null. That's the reason you're getting a Null Pointer Exception.